# Hibernate MySQLMyISAMDialect doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, myisam

I'm using hibernate 4.2.1 and MySQL 5.5 .

In persistence.xml i have this :

```
<!-- ... -->
<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect" />

</properties>
```

But When i run my projet my database doesn't contain any table !

Does anyone have any idea ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dialect line from your config entirely.

Hibernate can detect which dialect to use based on the underlying database metadata assuming you give it the correct username/password. I've never had a problem with Hibernate autodetecting my database version. It's especially useful with MySQL, because MySQL has different versions of dialects that it can use.

If you see the following exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

It means that your username/password is incorrect, and Hibernate couldn't connect to the database, to actually read the metadata to choose it's own dialect.

I have found that it is easier to set up the database tables using SQL scripts, then get Hibernate to `validate` your schema. Getting Hibernate to generate any database structure (using `create-update` or just `update`) is not recommended for a production environment, because you lose the control over how the database is set up.

TL;DR: Let Hibernate choose its own dialect. It will save you hours of fuss.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have already remove the dialect line from my persistence.xml but hibernate still generate to me a InnoDB storage's database !!.Should i,also, remove this:<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />. Thanks

Comment: No, if Hibernate is using the InnoDB dialect, then your database is using the InnoDB Storage Engine not the older ISAM storage engine. Its a setting on your database. But ISAM is an older technology than InnoDB.